# Регулярное выражение для поиска строки после двух знаков ","

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для Notepad++, где все строки такие:

> текст,текст,ТОЧТО-нужно оставить

проблема в то, что когда нажимаю найти и заменить на пустой символ, он стирает весь документ. Хотя я по идее, регулярным выражением выбираю то что нужно:

> **[\s\S]*?(?=,)**

Comment: не получается две запятые отфильтровать, и забрать текст который после второй запятой

Comment: как будто не работает ни один вариант ни второй

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно не текст после двух запятых искать, а текст с этими двумя запятыми. Ведь именно его потом заменим на пустоту.

Вот этот шаблон ищет любые символы (нежадно) с последующей запятой, два раза:

```
(.+?,){2}
```

Проверил в Notepad++. Работает, находит, заменяет.

Answer (score 1):

Заменить `^[^,]*,[^,]*,(.*)$` на `$1`.

[image: скриншот]